# From ActiveRecord to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, amazon-s3

I am new to S3 and Rails so got stuck. I am wondering if I can directly pass object to S3.

My controller:

```
def start_upload
  @forecasts = Forecast.all
  Forecast.export_to_s3(@forecasts) 
end
```

Model:

```
def self.export_to_s3(data)
  ---AWS configs ---
  Aws.config = { :access_key_id => aws_access_key, :secret_access_key => aws_secret_access_key, :region => aws_region }

  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:aws_region)

   resp = s3.put_object(
     :bucket => aws_bucket,
     :key => aws_bucket_key_forcast,
     :body => IO.read(data)
   )
end
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What's not working?

Comment: "no implicit conversion of Forecast::ActiveRecord_Relation into String". I guess I will join as string and try again.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? What is you goal?

You should try to serialize your object before you push it to your bucket.

```
def start_upload
  @forecasts = Forecast.all
  Forecast.export_to_s3(@forecasts.to_json) 
end

def self.export_to_s3(data)
  # ---AWS configs ---
  Aws.config = { :access_key_id => aws_access_key, :secret_access_key => aws_secret_access_key, :region => aws_region }

  tmpfile = Tempfile.new('forecast')
  tmpfile.write(data)
  tmpfile.close

  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region:aws_region)
  resp = s3.put_object(
           :bucket => aws_bucket,
           :key => aws_bucket_key_forcast,
              :body => IO.read(tmpfile)
            )
  tmpfile.unlink
end
```

Comment: I am trying to push data to bucket.  Data looks like this: January,2015,100.0,Trafic
It says in doc that - data (String, Pathname, File, IO) — The data to upload. This may be a: * String * Pathname * File * IO * Any object that responds to #read and #eof?.

Comment: Yes, it did not like it.
Errno::ENAMETOOLONG in ForecastsController#start_upload.


I changed to string but it does not work. I am doing something wrong. 
    input = data.map{|k,v| "#{v}"}.join(',')
    puts input

    resp = s3.get_object(:bucket => aws_bucket, :key =>     aws_bucket_key_forcast)
    resp.body.write(input)

Comment: Ok, the put_object method requires a file as string or an IO Object. So, try to write a tmp file and upload it that way.

Comment: Yep. it worked with tempfile.  I thought I can work with record object and push that way. Thank you so much.